Can not get the value after setting it
Im trying to get the value from that function :
        private void MyPlotModel_MouseDown(object sender, OxyMouseDownEventArgs ex)
        {
            OxyPlot.ElementCollection<OxyPlot.Axes.Axis> axisList = SpectralPlotModel.Axes;

            Axis xAxis = axisList.FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Position == AxisPosition.Bottom);
            Axis yAxis = axisList.FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Position == AxisPosition.Left);

            NearestPoint = OxyPlot.Axes.Axis.InverseTransform(ex.Position, xAxis, yAxis);
            Debug.Print("Nearest Point: " + NearestPoint);
        }

The value i get is a random number from my plot , its working fine ,after this i set it like this :
public DataPoint NearestPoint
{
    get
    {
        Debug.Print($"Entered Get {_nearestPoint}!!!"); 
        return _nearestPoint; 
    }
    set
    {
        Debug.Print($"Entered Set {value}!!!");
        _nearestPoint = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NearestPoint));
    }
}

The print in set is also working but the print when i call the get its printing zero , any ideas what im doing wrong?
I call that variable from that function :
        public async void OnLockChanged(int scanWindow, int intesityThreshold)
        {
            Debug.Print($"Points: {NearestPoint}, scanWindowSeconds: {scanWindow},Threshold: {intesityThreshold}");
        }

Thanks.
======================================================
Edited :
xaml.cs file from where it triggers the onLockChange (this function its inside of one of my components MVVM class) :
    public class xxxViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        // Variables
        private PlotViewModel _plotViewModel;

        private bool _isLocked;
        private int _scanWindow;
        private int _intesityThreshold;

        public xxxViewModel()
        {
            _plotViewModel = new PlotViewModel();
            LockCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteLockCommand);
        }

        public int ScanWindow
        {
            get => _scanWindow;
            set
            {
                if (_scanWindow != value)
                {
                    _scanWindow = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public int IntesityThreshold
        {
            get => _intesityThreshold;
            set
            {
                if (_intesityThreshold != value)
                {
                    _intesityThreshold = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        //ICommand
        public ICommand LockCommand { get; }

        private void ExecuteLockCommand(object parameter)
        {
            _plotViewModel.OnLockChanged(_scanWindow, _intesityThreshold);
        }
    }


Also if it helps , another example -> mouseWavelengthClick is not working so maybe i need to set a constructor or something ?
I just declare them as variables for now ,this variable its inside the same class and its not used or taken from another class :
        private ScreenPoint mouseDownPoint;
        private int waveLengthIndex;
        private bool mouseWavelengthClick = false;

private List<PointData> GetWavelength(double[] yData)
{
    var wavelength = new double[4096];
 ................
    for (int i = 0; i < yData.Length; i++)
    {
        pointData.Add(new PointData { X = wavelength[i], Y = yData[i] });
       if (mouseWavelengthClick)
       {
          Debug.Print("Wavelength : " + i);
          waveLengthIndex = i;
          mouseWavelengthClick = false;
        }
       
}


 private void MyPlotModel_MouseDown(object sender, OxyMouseDownEventArgs ex)
 {
     mouseWavelengthClick = true;
     OxyPlot.ElementCollection<OxyPlot.Axes.Axis> axisList = SpectralPlotModel.Axes;

     Axis xAxis = axisList.FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Position == AxisPosition.Bottom);
     Axis yAxis = axisList.FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Position == AxisPosition.Left);

     NearestPoint = OxyPlot.Axes.Axis.InverseTransform(ex.Position, xAxis, yAxis);
     //Debug.Print("Nearest Point: " + NearestPoint);
 }



async void, hmm.. and it's not an event handler. Still you need to show [mcve].

If the value is correct when setting _nearestPoint, but wrong when you get _nearestPoint, some other bit of code must be changing the value of _nearestPoint. Look through all references to _nearestPoint and try to find it.

I have not used anywhere else this variable,i've tried also to use a new variable inside a random function and use that variable to another one in the same class, but this variable also has zero value so i think im doing something wrong with init of the variables-constructor thing maybe ? Im also using MVVM so  those functions are inside a MVVM class . I will try to put some more info in my post and edit it.
